# Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1 Screen Tearing - nvidia-settings only showing two options

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia

I'm having screen tearing on my Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1 + Nvidia GTX 960 setup.

I installed nvidia-settings and thought that it should be resolvable from the panel, but unfortunately it's only showing me two options in the sidebar, whereas I saw more in tutorials (nvidia-settings is on version 390.77):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux Mint 19.1 there is a Driver Manager that is meant for installing (not only) the Nvidia drivers, example on my laptop:

[image: my nvidia driver manager]

I personally avoid installing those drivers via other means, thus so far no problem appeared. <strike>It is the recommended way under Linux Mint.</strike> It is thus my personal recommendation.

Comment: Using the Driver Manager and installing the metapackage in command-line interface is the same. One could see your answer as primarily opinion based, even though Linux Mint documentation displays the same way of doing so, nothing says it is the "recommended way".

Comment: @Paradox Good point. Strikken out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the driver using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

Fixed it for me. Not sure how the version affects the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Will the above snippet now work as-is without the PPA?

Comment: This is because you installed the metapackage, including the corresponding version of `nvidia-settings`, along with the driver.